# Не определено имя метода

Tags: python, python-3.x

Хочу нарисовать квадратик, который будет появляться в случайном месте окна.
Но выдает ошибку в 33 строке: `name 'draw' is not defined`. Подскажите пожалуйста, что делаю не так?

```
import turtle
import time
import random


class Rectangle:

def __init__(self, x, y):

    self.x = x
    self.y = y

def draw(self):

    self.color('black') 
    self.penup() 
    self.setpos(x, y) 
    self.pendown() 
    self.goto(x + 50, y) 
    self.goto(x + 50, y + 50)
    self.goto(x, y + 50)
    self.goto(x, y)

rect1 = Rectangle(random.randint(-200, 200), random.randint(-200, 200))        

turtle.tracer(0, 0) 
turtle.hideturtle()
rect1 = turtle.Turtle() 
rect1.hideturtle()

while True:
    time.sleep(0.5)
    rect1.clear() 
    draw(rect1) #ошибка
    turtle.update()
```

Comment: наверно надо было вызывать как метод `rect1.draw()`

Comment: @slippyk, тогда получается ошибка: ''Turtle' object has no attribute 'draw'' там же

Comment: правильно, по коду сначала `rect1 = Rectangle`, потом идет переопределение `rect1 = turtle.Turtle() `, и вызывается `draw(rect1)`, эта функция нигде не описана, есть только метод класса `Rectangle().draw()`

Comment: какая логика в этом коде?

Comment: @slippyk а как тогда правильно сделать?

Answer (score 2):

```
import turtle
import random


class Rectangle:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def draw(self, turtle):
        turtle.color('black')
        turtle.setpos(self.x, self.y)
        turtle.clear()
        turtle.goto(self.x + 50, self.y) 
        turtle.goto(self.x + 50, self.y + 50)
        turtle.goto(self.x, self.y + 50)
        turtle.goto(self.x, self.y)

turtle.Turtle()
turtle.tracer(0, 0)
turtle.hideturtle()

rect1 = Rectangle(random.randint(-200, 200), random.randint(-200, 200))
rect1.draw(turtle)

turtle.update()
turtle.mainloop()
```

Comment: Я бы `def draw(self):` -> `def draw(self, turtle):`, ну и `rect1.draw()` -> `rect1.draw(turtle)`

Comment: @gil9red подправил